# Origin of suffixes -арь- and -аль-

Tags: морфология, заимствования, суффиксы

I wonder whether the following suffixes in fact the Latin borrowings?

-арь- as in вратарь, писарь, мытарь

-аль- as in брутальный, паяльный, читальный

Answer (score 5):

[ru.wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B5) agrees w.r.t. -арь, referencing Antoine Meillet *Le slave commun*:

> *-arjь (суффикс профессии, отсюда рус. -арь) < прагерм. *-arjoz < лат. -arius

"Аль" is not a single suffix.

- There's '-л-' in words like пада-л-ь, бы-л-ь, порос-л-ь (it's a suffix signifying a phenomenon; some words with -аль are here)
- then there's '-л-' in words like чита-л-ьня, вмести-л-ище (it's an interfix, i.e. has no semantic value of its own; some words with -аль- in them are in this category)
- and then there are words like брутальный, лояльный, стерильный which are borrowed wholesale (many words with -аль-, this one is derived from Latin -alis)

There are other meanings of the -л- suffix, but these don't seem to produce any -аль- combinations.

Comment: Do you mean паяльный, читальный, меняльный were wholesale borrowed?

Comment: No, of course not. They belong to the second category.

Answer (score 4):

Despite that Vasmer in fact ignores the words with “-арь” suffix, the comparison of terms having that suffix drops hints about it‘s latin roots:

> -ārius *m* (*f.* -āria, *n.* -ārium)

See: псарь, свинарь, виноградарь, ключарь, чеботарь, ложкарь, штукарь, плугарь, пушкарь, косарь, кобзарь, библиотекарь, аптекарь, почтарь, корчмарь, волгарь (and it‘s derivative «болгар[ин]»), главарь, бунтарь, пескарь, словарь, букварь.

The etymology of “-аль” is more vague. In “дуальный” and “натуральный” it’s definitely derived from Latin “duālis”/“nātūrālis”:

> -ālis *m*, *f* (*n.* -āle)

But there is as well “москаль”, which looks like awry “москарь”. And there are “планетарный”, “легендарный” etc which have no affiliation with humans (as proper “-arius“ do.)

Since “р” and “л” sound quite similar, I would suggest that both those suffices are originated to their latin analogues, but nowadays some of they migrate from one to another according to common rules of russian language.

Comment: What does it mean "to drop hint"? Can you clarify, please?

Comment: English also has "planetary", "legendary", so I suspect the suffix has Latin origin (-aris)

Comment: “to drop hint” ≡ “to suggest,” I guess. AFAIK, there are no direct borrowings in russian from latin. Russian language mostly adopted Romano-Germanic terms (as well as Romanic from French.) And “r” and “l” are still quite similar (ask Nipponeses :-). The collision preventing me of claiming “-ar” suffix to be direct ancestor of “-ārius” is that “ārius” clearly indicates *a person*.

Comment: Note that the English for “планетарный” is "planetary" and for “легендарный” it's "legendary", also with R, which means it wasn't in Russian that those suffixes were added to those words.